# First Metamask ETH transaction Ropsten faucet failed

Tags: metamask, ether

I'm following the instructions off the book Mastering Ethereum, (https://www.onlineprogrammingbooks.com/mastering-ethereum/) and I've hit a snag.
I've set up the MetaMask extension and trying to make the first transaction via the Ropsten network. I'm getting the error:

`{"error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"replacement transaction underpriced\"}}'"}`

MetaMask is set up on Brave. I've tried with and without VPN.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got this error as well:

```
{"error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"replacement transaction underpriced\"}}'"}
```

For me, I turned off my adblocker and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried again a few days later and it just worked. It might have been a problem with my VPN after all.